# RxJS - Array.observe is not supported on your platform

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to make a basic example with RxJS, but I'm getting an error that says:

> rx.all.js:2880 Uncaught TypeError: Array.observe is not supported on your platform

This is my code right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script src="node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js"></script>

<script>
    var array = [];

    var observable = new Rx.Observable.ofArrayChanges(array);

    observable.subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res.object[res.index]);
    });

    setInterval(() => {
        array.push(Math.random());
    }, 1000);
</script>


</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you think of a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

`ofArrayChanges` is just a thin wrapper around the `Array.observe` functionality, an experimental technology proposal that has since been rejected and will likely be removed in the future.

See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-observe

As you can see functionality only really existed for 3 versions of chrome and 1 of opera, so if your application will be used outside of that (probably a safe assumption) then you will likely need to change your approach.

Comment: Right, so what would be another approach I can take?

Comment: I have seen Rx.Observable.ofArrayChanges() (for example) used in teaching course materials, so beware sample code that gives you this exception. It would seem from it's demise, this is the only useful purpose anyone has found for it.